# Controller improperly passing nil

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, controllers

I'm really new to rails and I've been struggling with sending data from the controller to views. I have a controller frame in which I have some `where` conditions in order to pass that data to the view however it appears to be `nil` when it isn't

My controller is like this (I know it's messy, I'm sorry)

```
class FrameController < ApplicationController
   before_action :authenticate_user!

   def contract
     @offer_c = Offer.where(user_id: current_user.id)
     @contract_o = Contract.where(offer_id: @offer_c)
     @user_cliente = Contract.where(user_id: current_user.id)
     @user_ofertante = Contract.where(id: @contract_o)
     @offer_cliente = @user_clinete.offer_id
     @oferta_completa = Offer.where(id: @offer_cliente)
     @oferta_usuario = User.where(id: @offer_cliente.user_id)
   end
 end
```

My view is like this

```
<% if @user_cliente %>
  <% @user_ofertante.each do |contract| %>
     <% @offer_c.each do |offer| %>
       <% if contract.offer_id == offer.id %>
         <div class="dropdown-divider">Mías</div>
           <a class="dropdown-item" href="#notificacion" data-toggle="modal">
             <strong>Oferta: </strong><%=offer.name%>
             <p>
               <strong>Usuario: </strong><%= User.where(id: Contract.user_id).first.firstName%>
             </p>
           </a>
         </div>
       <%end%>
     <%end%>
   <%end%>
 <%end%>
```

Now I know it is not working as it is supposed to because I have a user with `current_user.id = 2` and a contract with `user_id =2`.

When I put `@user_cliente = Contract.where(user_id: current_user.id)` in the view with `<% if @user_cliente %>` and it does not execute the code that follows however when i put the same `Contract.where(user_id: current_user.id)` in the console the contract does appear not just null. As the following picture show:

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: try to put logger.info"<--------#{@user_cliente.inspect}--->" in your controller at the end of method. so you can check in log whether it is giving data or not.

Comment: if you get any error in view, than please mention error here

Comment: Your console log (please paste the output into your question in the future instead of linking to an image) shows that there is a `Contact` with a given `user.id`. But do the other `where` conditions for `@user_ofertante` and `@offer_c` return records too for the same `user.id` and is then there still a `contract.offer_id == offer.id`? It might be easier if you write what kind of records you actually want to show and try to load them in one query?